# Почему не работает условие If

Tags: php, mysql, if

Есть html форма для фильтрации вывода таблиц в БД, где есть 3 select

Это значить проверяем на пустоту value  с помощью if else веток и делаем sql запрос. У меня работает только когда две select не пусты, а когда выбираю 3 select (**например sity, type, metal**) не работает проверка на пустоту или sql запрос, в чем дело?

[image: Функция подключения и отправка запроов в БД]

[image: Записываю Value по удобнее]

[image: Проверка на пустоту и выполняю sql запрос]

Comment: вставляйте код текстом, никому картинки ваши не итересны

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: я вставляю код а он его наполовину интерпретирует что ли или что короче пол кода куда то исчезает